# Odds of winning division 1 Powerball

Tags: permutations

The odds of winning division 1 [Powerball](https://www.thelott.com/powerball/play?jid=weekly-offers-powerball) is stated to be $134490400:1$. That is, you guess the exact draw of 7 unique balls from a drum with 35 balls, and the correct Powerball from another drum that has 20 unique balls.

[image: Powerball Game]

<sup>[Source](https://www.thelott.com/powerball/play?jid=weekly-offers-powerball)</sup>

---

I can't figure out how they got these odds. I calculated $\left(^{35} P_{7}\right) \cdot 20 = 677831616000$ possible ticket permutations. Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **order** in which you select the numbers is irrelevant here, thus you will get the correct answer as

$\binom{35}7\times 20 =134490400$ **combinations**

of which only one will give you the division 1 prize